# How can I get the text of the result in AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need the content of the Variable data from this AJAX Request but in a PHP Variable.
Is that possible?

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    async: false,
    url: '/php/checkAccountData.php', 
    data: 'un=' + PasswordResetUsernameText + '&e=' + PasswordResetEmailText,
    success: function(data){

        var responseanswer = data;

        alert(responseanswer);
    setTimeout(function(){
    $("img[name=UserNameEmailText]").fadeTo(500,0);
    $("div[id=PasswordResetLoadingDiv]").fadeOut(500)}, 1500);
    setTimeout(function(){
    $("img[name=UserNameEmailComplete]").fadeTo(500,1)}, 2500);
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('MainFrame').fadeTo(500,1);
    $('#LoginField').fadeOut(500, "swing")}, 7000000);
   }
```

Comment: No. PHP is a server-side language; AJAX is a client-side technology. You can, in a sense, pass PHP data to JavaScript, but not the other way around.

Comment: Please explain what it is you're actually trying to achieve, rather than "I tried this and it didn't do what I thought"...

Comment: Nope, no can do, only way I see would be to have another ajax request on success of the first ajax, to send the data to another php file where you could use it in theory. But seems a bit overkill... why not just execute the php in the checkAccountData.php file?